# Reactive cursor without updating UI for added record

Tags: meteor, reactive-programming, meteor-blaze

I am trying to make a newsfeed similar to twitter, where new records are not added to the UI (a button appears with new records count), but updates, change reactively the UI.

I have a collection called NewsItems and I a use a basic reactive cursor (NewsItems.find({})) for my feed. UI is a Blaze template with a each loop.
Subscription is done on a route level (iron router).

Any idea how to implement this kind of behavior using meteor reactivity ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed it using a session variable for the current date /time:

```
Template.newsFeed.onCreated(function () {
var tpl           = this;
tpl.loaded      = new ReactiveVar(0);
tpl.limit       = new ReactiveVar(30);
Session.set('newsfeedTime', new Date());

tpl.autorun(function () {
  var limit = tpl.limit.get();
  var time  = Session.get('newsfeedTime');

  var subscription = tpl.subscribe('lazyload-newsfeed', time, limit);
  var subscriptionCount = tpl.subscribe('news-count',  time);

  if (subscription.ready()) {
   tpl.loaded.set(limit);
  }
});

tpl.news = function() {
   return NewsItems.find({creationTime: {$lt: Session.get('newsfeedTime')}},
                    {sort: {relevancy: -1 }},
                    {limit: tpl.loaded.get()});
 },

 tpl.countRecent = function() {
   return Counts.get('recentCount');
 },

  tpl.displayCount = function() {
    return Counts.get('displayCount');
  }
});

Template.newsFeed.events({
   'click .load-new': function (evt, tpl) {
     evt.preventDefault();
     var time            = new Date();
     var limit          = tpl.limit.get();
     var countNewsToAdd  = tpl.countRecent();
     limit += countNewsToAdd;
     tpl.limit.set(limit);
     Session.set('newsfeedTime', new Date());
   }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The trick is to have one more attribute on the NewsItem Collection Say `show` which is a boolean. NewsItem should have default value of `show` as `false`

The Each Loop Should display only Feeds with `show == true` and button should show the count of all the items with `show == false`

On Button click update all the elements in the Collection with `show == false` to `show = true` 
this will make sure that all your feeds are shown .

As and when a new feed comes the Button count will also increase reactively .

Hope this Helps

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to update the local collection (`yourCollectionArticles._collection`): all articles are {show: false} by default except the first data list (in order not to have a white page).

You detect first collection load using  :

```
Meteor.subscribe("articles", {
        onReady: function () {
            articlesReady = true;
        }
    });
```

Then you observe new added data using

```
newsItems = NewsItems.find({})

newsItems.observeChanges({
        addedBefore: (id, article, before)=> {
            if (articlesReady) {
                article.show = false;
                NewsItems._collection.update({_id: id}, article);
            }
            else {
                article.show = true;
                NewsItems._collection.update({_id: id}, article);
            }
        }
});
```

Here is a working example: https://gist.github.com/mounibec/9bc90953eb9f3e04a2b3.